# Unable to install Cordova Network plugin

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I have created a fresh ionic 3 application and tried to install `https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information` plugin to the application. I executed below command:

```
ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information.git
```

This didn't install the plugin. Instead, it shows

> (node:14784) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): CordovaError: Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information.git via registry.
>   Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.

Any idea? or suggestions what's going on? I have tried installing other native plugins like device plugin has the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried doing `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information`?

Comment: Yes. I tried both ways

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to sort out the issue. credits to @Brass. I uninstalled node, ionic and cordova. After that, Installed Node.js latest version. Also executed

> npm cache clean -f
>   npm install -g cordova ionic

Hope this will helpful for someone else too.

Cheer!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried following the Ionic docs?
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
npm install --save @ionic-native/network
```

Comment: Before you do this, you have to install via git repo. BTW I tried that too. It didn't install the plugin

Comment: That is not correct.  You DO NOT need to install via the git repo before executing the steps above.  I have installed this plugin without ever referencing the git repo.  Do you get the same error when executing the steps from the Ionic docs (and not referencing the git repo)?

Comment: I started a clean ionic project and installed the plugin via the ionic docs steps, and via the git repo.  Both worked fine for me.  Sounds like you have an environmental issue.  Please update your post with some details about your environment (e.g. output from `ionic info`).  Also, what happens if you try to install other plugins?  Do those work?

Comment: Thanks @BRass, I created a fresh project too. Didn't work. So, I assumed that is something to do with my environment. You are correct.

Comment: Do you get the same error for other plugin install attempts?  Also, can you provide the output from `ionic info`?

Comment: Yes, I got the same error. Btw two weeks back it was working fine. I think some updates changed my Env. I'm sorry I couldn't get the ionic info before it uninstalled :(